# Referencing excel cells inserted in a word document

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word

Does anybody know how to reference cells from an excel document inserted into a word document, so when the cells are updated (in the word document) it automatically updated elsewhere in the word document.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could link a excel by using `insert-->object`

choose `object -->create from file`

choose your excel and the cells would be placed inside the excel

From now on, when you update the Excel file, the table in Word will also be updated. Be aware, however, that you will need to repeat the previous steps if you change the location or name of the Excel file.

Comment: You left out an important detail. If they don't check the `Link to file` checkbox Word will not update.